# How add more than one dependency in Gradle build file?

Tags: gradle

This question may be silly but, I could not find a simple example how to add more than one dependency to dependencies closure in a gradle file the example given in the documentations is :

```
dependencies {
 compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
}
```

What if I want add spring and Hibernate and other  ?

Comment: Or just read the entire user guide PDF that comes with the distribution. Simple issues like this are easily answered in the user guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
    compile 'some:other-dependency:1.8.3'
}
```

You may also want to read [Gradle Dependency Management Basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) and [Advanced Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)